# Wordpress Loop to Show all userposts but with post_date

Tags: wordpress, while-loop, posts

How do i get the date of the posts beside of the postname in a list? i tried it with following code which will show all the post name of the users posts but only the first one gets a date and i guess it is the date of today not of the post itself.

```
 <!-- the loop -->
<?php while ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : $wpb_all_query->the_post(); ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?><?php the_date(); ?></a></li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<!-- end of the loop -->
```

whereas this code posts the name of the post and the content for each one of them. is that with the date a bug?

```
<ul>

    <!-- the loop -->
    <?php while ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : $wpb_all_query->the_post(); ?>
        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?><?php the_content(); ?></a></li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <!-- end of the loop -->

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `the_date()` will only display once per page per day according to the Wordpress Codex and other posts on Wordpress Development Stack Exchange https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/125209. The solution is to use the function `get_the_date()` instead.

Comment: I just tried it like this "<?php get_the_date(); ?>" but didn't get any date

Comment: Try `<?php echo get_the_date(); ?>`